# SharePoint 2010 Custom List and Attachments

Tags: sharepoint-2010, attachment, custom-lists, sharepoint-api

I have created Custom List with few columns namely:

```
Title
Description
HrefLink
```

And optionally upload Attachments to the list item.

My scenario is as following, fetch the data from the list and print the data in list with hyperlink. Here, for hyperlink I should attach the any attachment is there for an item else pull the HrefLink field value.

How can I find if a list item has an attachment and how can I pull the path of attachment and print it?

Comment: What API are you using? Server-side, client-side?

Answer (score 0):

I have achived fetching the attachments using the following login and printed to literal:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
     using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
         {
             using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
                    {

                        /*Footer - Hotspot Links */
                        //Define string builder to attach the fetched content
                        StringBuilder strFooterHotspotLinks = new StringBuilder();

                        SPList lstFooterHotspotLinks = currentWeb.Lists["Footer Hotspot Links"];

                        //Difine list query
                        SPQuery spQryFooterHotspotLinks = new SPQuery();
                        spQryFooterHotspotLinks.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Hotspot_x0020_Order' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";
                        spQryFooterHotspotLinks.RowLimit = 5;

                        SPListItemCollection lstItmFooterHotspotLinks = lstFooterHotspotLinks.GetItems(spQryFooterHotspotLinks);

                        int lnkCount = 1;

                        if (lstItmFooterHotspotLinks.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (SPListItem itmFooterHotspotLinks in lstItmFooterHotspotLinks)
                            {

                                String qlAttachmentAbsUrl = itmFooterHotspotLinks.Attachments.UrlPrefix;    //gets the containing directory URl
                                SPAttachmentCollection qlAttachments = itmFooterHotspotLinks.Attachments;   //check the attachment exists or not for list item

                                //If list attachmetns are existing
                                if (qlAttachments.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    //Loop the list to find the attachments exist ot not and attach to the link
                                    foreach (String qlAttachmentName in qlAttachments)
                                    {
                                        strFooterHotspotLinks.Append("<li><a href='" + qlAttachmentAbsUrl + qlAttachmentName + "'><span class='icn-" + lnkCount + "'></span>" + itmFooterHotspotLinks["Hotspot Title"] + "</a></li>");
                                        lnkCount++;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    strFooterHotspotLinks.Append("<li><a href='" + itmFooterHotspotLinks["Hotspot Link"] + "'><span class='icn-" + lnkCount + "'></span>" + itmFooterHotspotLinks["Hotspot Title"] + "</a></li>");
                                    lnkCount++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```